# iOS apps installed from outside the AppStore

Tags: ios

I'll start by saying that I'm pretty new to iOS apps.

I remember I installed an app from their website while they were in beta. Since this was possible(2 months ago).

1. Is it still possible today? Does it still require to be register in Apple's Developer Program?
2. I know one can develop iOS apps in Adobe AIR. Can the apps be installed without the Apple Program(from outside the AppStore/on your own iPhone for testing purpose)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes you'll get an icon an the home screen that looks like an app but it's actually a shortcut to a web app.

You can install apps from outside the App Store - compiling it yourself, or having someone send you the ipa and a provisioning profile. But this requires your device id to be added to the developer's developer account (unless they have an Enterprise licence, in which case they can distribute it to anyone).

[Testflight](http://testflightapp.com) lets you download apps for testing, but the developer needs to have created a profile with your device id.

Comment: no no, I can guarantee the app I installed wasn't an HTML5 app. It was an iOS app that I installed from their website. The iPhone asked if I agree to have it installed and then proceeded just like with any other app(loading/installing steps)

Comment: with Testflight I can install the app on iPhones without the developer certificate?

Comment: @Andrew - As I said, if a developer has an Enterprise account they can install apps to any device. With Testflight, only the developer needs an account; testers don't. They only need to provide their device id to the developer so he can add them to his account.